# Dynamic legend labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I defined a data structure for storing legend labels as follows (because I want to produce mutliple plots with different data and different labels in a row).

```
legendlabels <- data.frame(
                    'stadtland'=c("Core City\n(Agglomeration)","Municipality\n(Agglomeration)", "Isolated City", "Rural\nMunicipality"),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now, when I use `legendlabels` within a `ggplot` like this,

```
... + 
scale_colour_hue(name="Type",
                     breaks=as.factor(c(1:4)),
                     labels=legendlabels['stadtland'],
                     l=65) +
...
```

the legend merely displays "1","2","3","4" for the 4 different labels. However, when I insert the vector directly (undynamically), the strings get displayed correctly:

```
... + 
scale_colour_hue(name="Type",
                     breaks=as.factor(c(1:4)),
                     labels=c("Core City\n(Agglomeration)","Municipality\n(Agglomeration)", "Isolated City", "Rural\nMunicipality"),
                     l=65) +
...
```

How can I substitute this?

Comment: Maybe try `labels=legendlabels[['stadtland']]` instead? Don't forget the difference between `[` and `[[`!

Comment: Great. I forgot about that difference (or do not understand it). If you post this as an answer with a small explanation of the difference between `[]` and `[[]]`, I'll accept it. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment,

```
labels=legendlabels['stadtland']
```

will return a list of length one, not the atomic vector you are looking for. Instead, you want to use `[[`:

```
labels=legendlabels[['stadtland']]
```

which returns the *element* named `stadtland` from the list (data frames are lists) `legendlabels`.